# Setting up a second TFDPhysFBDriverLink - possible and necessary?

Tags: delphi, driver, firebird, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

My application has a design time `TFDConnection` and `TFDPhysFBDriverLink` as source connection. This may or may not be opened in Firebird embedded mode (if so, `FDPhysFBDriverLink.VendorLib := 'fbembed.dll'` is set (32 bits)).

I create a run-time target `TFDConnection` which *must* use embedded Firebird because we do not know if Firebird is installed on the PC (our setup supplies `fbembed.dll`).

How do I set this up? At runtime I can create another `TFDPhysFBDriverLink` and set its VendorLib, but how does FireDAC know what its associated connection is? Or can I use only one `FDPhysFBDriverLink` in the application?

This is old code I'm converting, using [DirectSQL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directsql/), and this also used to set some magic `SDFib.SqlApiDLL := FBEMBED` property, which supposedly worked for the target database only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst case in your situation is that Firebird is installed, so one connection connects to that installed server instance whilst another to the embedded one. For that is enough to have one physical driver object, but there's no problem having more.

So, drop one [**TFDPhysFBDriverLink**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.FB.TFDPhysFBDriverLink) on a form or datamodule and setup its [**DriverID**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink.DriverID) property to a unique name (that is not used as base driver ID for any driver), and mark it as [**Embedded**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.FB.TFDPhysFBDriverLink.Embedded) (that has no practical meaning in case when you specify [**VendorLib**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink.VendorLib) at this time, but you can use it to identify the driver; FireDAC uses this property only for decision which default library should be loaded).

Then for one connection use [**DriverID**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink.DriverID) that you defined and for the other one use fallback to default Firebird driver settings by using its [**BaseDriverID**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink.BaseDriverID) (I've omitted settings unecessary for this task):

```
FDPhysFBDriverLink1.DriverID := 'FBEmbedded'; { ← ID not used by any BaseDriverID }
FDPhysFBDriverLink1.Embedded := True; { ← not mandatory when VendorLib is specified }
FDPhysFBDriverLink1.VendorLib := 'C:\fbembed.dll'; { ← client library file name }

FDConnection1.Params.DriverID := 'FB'; { ← driver's BaseDriverID }
FDConnection1.Open; { ← this will connect to the installed server }

FDConnection2.Params.DriverID := 'FBEmbedded'; { ← driver's DriverID }
FDConnection2.Open; { ← this will connect to the embedded server }
```

But I would prefer having two separate driver objects, one for installed server (with default settings, like base driver has) and one for embedded server. For example:

```
FDPhysFBDriverLink1.DriverID := 'FBEmbedded'; { ← ID not used by any BaseDriverID }
FDPhysFBDriverLink1.Embedded := True; { ← not mandatory when VendorLib is specified }
FDPhysFBDriverLink1.VendorLib := 'C:\fbembed.dll'; { ← client library file name }

FDPhysFBDriverLink2.DriverID := 'FBInstalled'; { ← ID not used by any BaseDriverID }

FDConnection1.Params.DriverID := 'FBEmbedded'; { ← driver 1 DriverID }
FDConnection1.Open; { ← this will connect to the embedded server }

FDConnection2.Params.DriverID := 'FBInstalled'; { ← driver 2 DriverID }
FDConnection2.Open; { ← this will connect to the installed server }
```

Comment: What does the Embedded property do? I can't find any documentation (*Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional information*)

Comment: It only loads `fbembed.dll` library instead of `fbclient.dll` in case `VendorLib` is not set. In this case it's useless (because you'll specify `VendorLib`), but I've used it for possible future additions (and you can use it to identify your driver).

Comment: OK, this works, thanks. I'm using two different TFDPhysFBDriverLinks. One thing I noted: I should not *both* assign a DriverName and a DriverID.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, `DriverName` clears connection definition and sets `DriverID` in `Params`. Setting the `DriverID` property (or setting it like key value pair `DriverID=FBEmbedded`) sets only `DriverID` in `Params`.